# Error manejando varios archivos en la memoria de la maquina virtual, Java heap space

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, programación-reactiva, spring-webflux

Explicando un poco, en esta parte lo que hago es descargar archivos desde otro microservicio que me devuelve como respuesta un Mono, quisiera saber si esta es la forma correcta de manejar este tipo de archivos ya que me sale un error de espacio en la memoria, entiendo que seria por que son muchos archivos pero el detalle es que en un inicio si procesa pero si sigo invocando nuevamente este proceso ya me sale el error de espacio.
Pareciese que no se eliminan cuando terminan su proceso.
Que podría ser ?

```
return documentoPorLoteDAO.getByLote(respuestaExpediente.getIdLote())
                        .flatMap(dxl -> clientes.archivoPorDocumento(token, dxl.getDocumento())
                        .flatMap(archivoBD -> {
                            String encryptedId = encryptor.encrypt(String.valueOf(archivoBD.getId()));
                            return Mono.fromCallable(() -> clientes.downloadFile(token, encryptedId, archivoBD.getNumeroUltimaVersion()))
                            .flatMap(file -> DataBufferUtils.join(file)
                                    .flatMap(data -> {
                                        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.readableByteCount()];
                                        data.read(bytes);
                                        DataBufferUtils.release(data);
                                        return Mono.just(bytes);
                                    }))
                            .map(bytes -> {
                                String archivoB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Este es el error que me sale:

```
2024-02-13T18:14:48.892-05:00 ERROR 1 --- [firma] [or-http-epoll-2] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector       : LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
    Recent access records:
    Created at:
            io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:404)
            io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
            io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
            io.netty.channel.unix.PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.java:53)
            io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:120)
            io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.allocate(EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.java:75)
            io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:785)
            io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:509)
            io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407)
            io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
            io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    2024-02-13T18:14:48.892-05:00  WARN 1 --- [firma] [or-http-epoll-1] reactor.core.Exceptions                  : throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:
    
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    
    2024-02-13T18:14:48.892-05:00  WARN 1 --- [firma] [or-http-epoll-1] reactor.core.Exceptions                  : throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:
    
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    
    2024-02-13T18:14:48.892-05:00  WARN 1 --- [firma] [or-http-epoll-1] i.n.c.AbstractChannelHandlerContext      : An exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
    
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```